# gulp connect html extension resource name resolution

Tags: gulp-connect

I have a `gulp-connect` reload function

```js
function reload(done) {
  server({
    livereload: true,
    root: '/home/kamil/my-website',
    port: 8080
  });
  done();
}
```

and I'm surprised to find that requesting `localhost:8080/index` doesn't resolve to the resource name `index.html`. Instead, I have to explicitly add the `.html` extension to the URL in order to get it, i.e. `localhost:8080/index.html`. Coming from JSP, where `return "index";` works just as well as `return "index.html";` that seems weird. Is there any reason for such a design decision? It's in the context of gulp connect, but maybe there is a general trend in js or frontend technologies? Generally speaking, is it often to be insensitive to HTML extension in resource resolution by such app servers?